# "java.sql.SQLException: OALL8 is in an inconsistent state" on JBoss

Tags: java, sql, jboss

I've got an application which is running on JBoss. Now I'm getting `java.sql.SQLException: OALL8 is in an inconsistent state` exception. I know this is a driver's fault. But I don't know how to change it in datasource, because I'm using `thin`. This is my standalone:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/TelecomDS" pool-name="Telecom" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
   <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin@192.168.100.11:1521:mydb</connection-url>
   <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
   <driver>OracleDriver</driver>
   <pool>
        <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
   </pool>
   <security>
         <user-name>username</user-name>
          <password>password</password>
    </security>
```

This connection works. How can I update driver or something?

**UPD**

```
15:31:38,611 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 9) DatabaseProductName: Oracle
15:31:38,617 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 9) DatabaseProductVersion: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production
15:31:38,627 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 9) With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, OLAP, Data Mining
15:31:38,636 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 9) and Real Application Testing options
15:31:38,642 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 9) =====  Driver info =====
15:31:38,648 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 9) DriverName: Oracle JDBC driver
15:31:38,654 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 9) DriverVersion: 11.1.0.7.0-Production
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[upgrade to 10.1.0.4 this bugs are fixed in 10.1.0.4.](https://community.oracle.com/thread/276018?tstart=0)

Comment: How should I upgrade it exactly?

Comment: Download the jar with the oracle jdbc driver and put it in your classpath

Comment: In classpath where? JBoss or app? Also I'm using JBoss datasource to connect.

Comment: Look where the other driver is and replace it.